# jQuery Date Picker tied up to an input text field error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a date range picker in jQuery and tie it to an input text field.

the code goes like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <script>

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
  });

  </script>


</head>
<body style="font-size:62.5%;">
  <form action="sample.php" method="post">

Start Date: <input type="text" name="startdate" id="datepicker"/>
End Date: <input type="text" name="enddate" id="datepicker"/>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Data seems to be working FOR the START DATE input text field. When I select the start date field, the calendar appears:

[image]

But when I click on the END DATE input text field, the calendar never appears. I need to select dates START and END by using that calendar.

Something must be wrong on my code. Can anyone tell me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hiya So you have 2 element start and end date with same `id = datepicker` which is incorrect.

see this for example: http://jsbin.com/evudo

Solution:

Please initialize for both the input boxes,

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#start_datepicker").datepicker();
    $("#end_datepicker").datepicker();

  });
```

HTML

```
Start Date: <input type="text" name="startdate" id="start_datepicker"/>
End Date: <input type="text" name="enddate" id="end_datepicker"/>
```

Hope it helps,
cheers

Answer (score 2):

you have given the same id for both elements.. ID value for an element should be unique in that document.

```
 <script>    
$(document).ready(function() {     
       $("#datepicker1").datepicker();   });    
       $("#datepicker2").datepicker();   });    

</script>   </head> 
<body style="font-size:62.5%;">   
<form action="sample.php" method="post">  
    Start Date: <input type="text" name="startdate" id="datepicker1"/> 
    End Date: <input type="text" name="enddate" id="datepicker2"/> 
<input type="submit" /> </form> 
</body> </html>
```

Or you can use a class,

```
 <script>    
$(document).ready(function() {     
       $(".datepicker").datepicker();   });    
</script>   </head> 
<body style="font-size:62.5%;">   
<form action="sample.php" method="post">  
    Start Date: <input type="text" name="startdate" class="datepicker"/> 
    End Date: <input type="text" name="enddate" class="datepicker"/> 
<input type="submit" /> </form> 
</body> </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

IDs should be unique according to the standards ,try changing the ID for start date and end date.
Or replace the id with class.

```
Start Date: <input type="text" name="startdate" class="datepicker"/>
End Date: <input type="text" name="enddate" class="datepicker"/>


 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker();
  });
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same id for both the input fields.
Try this

```
Start Date: <input type="text" name="startdate" id="datepicker_start"/>
End Date: <input type="text" name="enddate" id="datepicker_end"/>


$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datepicker_start").datepicker();
    $("#datepicker_end").datepicker();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Definition and Usage
The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document). from [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_id.asp)

if you want to have a date range using two text fields
try this

```
var dates = j$( "#trdatefrom, #trdateto" ).datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                maxDate: new Date(),
                dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd",
              onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
                        var option = this.id == "trdatefrom" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
                                instance = j$( this ).data( "datepicker" ),
                                date =j$.datepicker.parseDate(
                                        instance.settings.dateFormat ||
                                        j$.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                                        selectedDate, instance.settings );
                        dates.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );
                }
        });
```

from [jquery datepicker docu](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)

Comment: what has this got to do with this particular question?